# Alma linux 8 update fails for any package with GPG keys check fail

Tags: linux, dnf

I have upgraded a Centos7 server to Centos8 and then to Almalinux 8.8. If I run **dnf update** I get an error for any package. I have removed yum so I am using dnf. I have tried **dnf clean all** but the problem arises again when I do a **dnf update**. Here is the last part of my update log. I get the same error on every single package I am trying to update!

```
Public key for libstdc++-8.5.0-18.el8.alma.x86_64.rpm is not installed. Failing package is: libstdc++-8.5.0-18.el8.alma.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-AlmaLinux
Public key for ncurses-6.1-9.20180224.el8_8.1.x86_64.rpm is not installed. Failing package is: ncurses-6.1-9.20180224.el8_8.1.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-AlmaLinux
Public key for ncurses-base-6.1-9.20180224.el8_8.1.noarch.rpm is not installed. Failing package is: ncurses-base-6.1-9.20180224.el8_8.1.noarch
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-AlmaLinux
Public key for ncurses-libs-6.1-9.20180224.el8_8.1.x86_64.rpm is not installed. Failing package is: ncurses-libs-6.1-9.20180224.el8_8.1.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-AlmaLinux
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: GPG check FAILED
```

I have also tried this:

```
$ rpm --import "file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-AlmaLinux"
$ dnf clean packages
```

I am not sure if this is related because I am trying to install leapp-upgrade but get this error

```
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - package leapp-upgrade-el8toel9-0.18.0-1.el8.noarch requires leapp-repository-dependencies = 9, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package leapp-upgrade-el8toel9-0.18.0-1.el8_8.2.alma.noarch requires leapp-repository-dependencies = 9, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package leapp-upgrade-el8toel9-deps-0.18.0-1.el8.noarch requires systemd-container, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package leapp-upgrade-el8toel9-deps-0.18.0-1.el8_8.2.alma.noarch requires systemd-container, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package systemd-container-239-74.el8_8.2.i686 obsoletes systemd < 229-5 provided by systemd-219-78.el7_9.7.x86_64
  - package systemd-container-239-74.el8_8.2.x86_64 obsoletes systemd < 229-5 provided by systemd-219-78.el7_9.7.x86_64
  - package systemd-container-239-74.el8_8.3.i686 obsoletes systemd < 229-5 provided by systemd-219-78.el7_9.7.x86_64
  - package systemd-container-239-74.el8_8.3.x86_64 obsoletes systemd < 229-5 provided by systemd-219-78.el7_9.7.x86_64
  - package systemd-container-239-74.el8_8.5.i686 obsoletes systemd < 229-5 provided by systemd-219-78.el7_9.7.x86_64
  - package systemd-container-239-74.el8_8.5.x86_64 obsoletes systemd < 229-5 provided by systemd-219-78.el7_9.7.x86_64
  - package systemd-container-239-74.el8_8.i686 obsoletes systemd < 229-5 provided by systemd-219-78.el7_9.7.x86_64
  - package systemd-container-239-74.el8_8.x86_64 obsoletes systemd < 229-5 provided by systemd-219-78.el7_9.7.x86_64
  - package systemd-python-219-78.el7_9.7.x86_64 requires systemd = 219-78.el7_9.7, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package leapp-upgrade-el7toel8-0.14.0-100.202109271224Z.b7ebfca.master.el7.elevate.noarch requires leapp-repository-dependencies = 6, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package leapp-upgrade-el7toel8-0.16.0-6.el7.elevate.1.noarch requires leapp-repository-dependencies = 6, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package leapp-upgrade-el7toel8-1:0.16.0-6.el7.elevate.16.noarch requires leapp-repository-dependencies = 6, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package leapp-upgrade-el7toel8-1:0.16.0-6.el7.elevate.17.noarch requires leapp-repository-dependencies = 6, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package leapp-upgrade-el7toel8-1:0.16.0-6.el7.elevate.8.noarch requires leapp-repository-dependencies = 6, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package leapp-upgrade-el7toel8-0.16.0-6.el7.elevate.noarch requires leapp-repository-dependencies = 6, but none of the providers can be installed
  - problem with installed package systemd-python-219-78.el7_9.7.x86_64
  - nothing provides python-requests needed by leapp-upgrade-el7toel8-deps-0.14.0-100.202109271224Z.b7ebfca.master.el7.elevate.noarch
  - nothing provides python-requests needed by leapp-upgrade-el7toel8-deps-0.16.0-6.el7.elevate.1.noarch
  - nothing provides python-requests needed by leapp-upgrade-el7toel8-deps-1:0.16.0-6.el7.elevate.16.noarch
  - nothing provides python-requests needed by leapp-upgrade-el7toel8-deps-1:0.16.0-6.el7.elevate.17.noarch
  - nothing provides python-requests needed by leapp-upgrade-el7toel8-deps-1:0.16.0-6.el7.elevate.8.noarch
  - nothing provides python-requests needed by leapp-upgrade-el7toel8-deps-0.16.0-6.el7.elevate.noarch
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It may be that your keys are outdated. They are part of the almalinux-release package, so run `dnf upgrade almalinux-release` first. After that the other packages should validate again.

Comment: See also AlmaLinux blog post: https://almalinux.org/blog/2023-12-20-almalinux-8-key-update/